# Thread synchronization to avoid multiple downloading

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have several differents thread to download some files and it is possible that two different threads want to download the same file. It is also possible that the files are very large (> 100MB) and so I want to avoid to download one file twice.

My idea is to synchronize the threads. The first thread `t1` should download the file and the second thread `t2` which want to download the same file should wait until the file is downloaded from `t1` and then should be informed from the first thread that the download is completed.

My problem is also, that I have an undefined number of threads (possible more then 1000) and they are used on different places in the whole application.

I don't know how to do that in C#. Can anyone give me something to start one thinking, please.

*That's just a simple example to describe my problem*

Comment: You don't understand the problem. If i use lock, the other threads (other files to download) would also be waiting.

Comment: Well I would drop threads and use Tasks instead you can use ConcurrentDictionary to store the all the active tasks

Comment: Then make sure you have a manner of checking files already being downloaded and dont let it do the same one twice

Comment: Ok, read about concurrent collections then

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `Task Parallel Library` and use `ActionBlock<T>`. There you can set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1.

A simple example is:

```
void run()
{
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Uri>(DownloadUri, new 
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

    actionBlock.Post(new Uri("http://....."));
    actionBlock.Post(new Uri("http://....."));
    actionBlock.Post(new Uri("http://....."));
    actionBlock.Post(new Uri("http://....."));
}

public Task DownloadUri(Uri uri)
{
    ...
}
```